# Can you put QWidgets on the stack?

Tags: c++, qt, pointers, qwidget, qmessagebox

Backstory:

I had some of my code reviewed, and I had made a local `QMessageBox` for displaying an error, and allocated it to the heap:

```
if (getAutopilotList.error() == 0) {
    QMessageBox* error = new QMessageBox(0);
    error->setDetailedText(getAutopilotList.errorString());
    error->setText("something");
    error->setWindowTitle(tr("Error!"));
    error->show();
    return;
}
```

The developer said:

> This pointer will leak, you are setting no parent and you never delete
>   it. Here as well you do not need a pointer. As for the parent do not
>   use 0, but Core::ICore::mainWindow().

I was confused because I thought:

1. QWidgets only worked on the Heap
2. That the pointer would `delete error;` automatically when the messagebox was closed.

I tried putting the QMessageBox on the stack, but it did not show.

---

### Questions:

1. Can I put this QMessageBox on the stack and have it work, and should I?
2. Do I need to explicitly `delete` the QMessageBox pointer?
3. Why is setting the parent to something beyond 0 important in this case?

Comment: The `new QMessageBox(0)` is cargo cult coding. You simply want: `new QMessageBox`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In principle, you can create a QWidget object on the stack. Here, it wouldn't work because the call to `error->show()` does not show the message box immediately, it just schedules a display when back to the main even loop, at which time the object will be destroyed. For that reason, `delete`ing the `QMessageBox` is not going to work either. Setting the parent gives the responsability of the object destruction to the parent, when the parent is itself destroyed, and it is a good idea.

However, if I understand what you want to do, you want to wait for the user to click on the OK button before the `return`. If that's the case, you'd better use the static `QMessageBox` functions, such as [QMessageBox::warning](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmessagebox.html#warning).

If you want a persistent message box, then your code is OK, but you should add the following call:

```
error->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);
```

This will trigger deletion when the corresponding window is closed.

Comment: This is *the* most helpful answer to the question. The only one that shows the one missing line that will make the code work as desired!

Answer (score 4):

> I tried putting the QMessageBox on the stack, but it did not show.

Because it will get destroyed immediately when thread goes out of the scope. You had to use `QMessageBox::exec()` to run it in block-mode.

Answer (score 3):

QWidget on stack works, but not practical for most cases as the objects on stack are deleted, when the scope is left.

Take a look at any (many-many) Qt examples, and you'll find the pattern:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);   
    MainWindow window; //inherits from QWidget, created on stack
    window.show();    
    return app.exec();
}
```

1) Concerning the question "QWidget on stack"- It should be the prove, that it works and official. But again this and the QDialog::exec are pretty the only use cases for QWidgets on stack.

2) It won't harm. If your coding rules require to call delete for each new - do it. Otherwise, set Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose properly, and let it be deleted on close.

3)Regarding parent 0: You are safe when loosing the reference to the pointer having a parent. If the parent is deleted, all children are deleted automatically (also those, you may have been forgotten about). So for long-running applications, the "memory leak" will be only temporarily. 
With parent =0 it won't leak in c++ sense, and this makes impossible for memory checkers to detect such leaks. The pointer is still accessible using some QObject-tree traversing functions.